# Installing gcc on s390x

Tags: gcc, s390x

I need a C compiler on my s390, which runs RHEL 7.6. When I do "yum list | grep gcc", I have the following:

```
libgcc.s390x                     4.8.5-36.el7         
compat-gcc-44.s390x              4.4.7-8.el7                                
compat-gcc-44-c++.s390x          4.4.7-8.el7                                 
gcc.s390x                        4.8.5-16.el7                                
gcc-c++.s390x                    4.8.5-16.el7                                
gcc-gfortran.s390x               4.8.5-16.el7                                
gcc-objc.s390x                   4.8.5-16.el7                                
gcc-objc++.s390x                 4.8.5-16.el7                                
libgcc.s390                      4.8.5-16.el7
```

I then do: yum install gcc.s390x and I obtain the following error:

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.s390
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.s390x (@rhel-7-for-system-z-rpms)
               glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.3
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.s390x 
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
```

What I read from this is that s390x package is installed but the one needed is the one that does not have the s390 extension.

How can I get around this ? I pulling gcc directly from git but when I do a configure the message says that a compiler needs to be installed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks - C

Answer (score 0):

This output line

```
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.s390x
```

shows that the configured repositories only contain glibc versions up to [RHSA-2017:1916](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:1916). This means that you have configured repositories for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 (and not even Extended Update Support). However, someone at one point upgraded glibc to a package version from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.

Installing GCC needs additional glibc components, and these have to match the already-installed version. Since the 7.6 packages are not available from the configured repositories, installation fails with a dependency error.

If you need assistance with subscription management, you should [file a support ticket](https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/).

Comment: Thanks Florian for the feedback.